# objdump -W sees line numbers, objdump -drl and gdb don't?

Tags: gdb, libtool, objdump

There are a lot of questions with missing source files etc, and I tried all that I could find to no avail.

This is about a library of mine, with some helper applications. I use autotools (and libtool).

I have compiled my code with `-g` and no optimization (later tried with `-ggdb3` as well with no observable difference w.r.t this question). I have tried `gdb` on the installed file, as well as `libtool --mode=execute gdb build/dir/file` with no difference.

If I use `objdump -W`, I can see the following (let's take a random function and track only that):

```
$ objdump /usr/bin/that_file

 ...
 <1><a11>: Abbrev Number: 38 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <a12>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xbcc2): fill_memory  
    <a16>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 4       
    <a17>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 98      
    <a18>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1       
    <a18>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3c>  
    <a1c>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x4010ce        
    <a24>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x92 0x0        
    <a2c>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c        (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <a2e>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1    
    <a2e>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xa83> 
 ...

 The Directory Table:
 ...
 ../../../apps/calibrator
 ...

 The File Name Table:
 ...
 4     2       0       0       main.c
 ...
```

You can see that the symbol is at line 98 of `../../../apps/calibrator/main.c` relative to where the file was built.  If I use gdb, and do `info sources` (before running), I get:

```
(gdb) info sources
Source files for which symbols have been read in:



Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand:

..., /path/to/my/library/apps/calibrator/main.c
```

Which means `gdb` is correctly seeing that source file.  If I break on a function in `main.c` (such as `main`), I see that file still in files that "will be read in on demand", not in the ones that are already read.

If I do `info source`, at this point, it tells me "No current source file". If I use `objdump -dl`, I see:

```
00000000004010ce <fill_memory>:
fill_memory():
  4010ce:       55                      push   %rbp
  4010cf:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  ...
```

So `objdump -dl` also doesn't see the file/line numbers associated with that symbol. If in `gdb`, I do `list main`, I get "No line number known for main."

Why doesn't `objdump -dl` see the line numbers when `objdump -W` does? What am I missing?

Comment: Note: I just tried `-gstabs+` instead of `-ggdb3` and it seems to work. Why? Shouldn't `-ggdb3` be better suited to gdb?

Comment: Post note: using `-gstabs+`, I see inconsistencies. For example, a function parameter (pointer) is reported as `0x0` in gdb, but an immediate `printf` prints it correctly. In fact, `printf` with `&param` shows a different address that `p &param` does in `gdb`. The values as printed by `gdb` have the correct type and no other variable with the same name is defined globally.

Comment: Don't use stabs.  They are old and generally buggier and barely maintained in gdb and gcc.

Comment: Also, you didn't show exactly what happens if you try, e.g., "break fill_memory".

Comment: Are you perhaps using relatively new GCC and binutils with a relatively old GDB? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28132451/50617

Comment: @TomTromey, `break fill_memory` works as expected. `gdb` stops on the function, but doesn't show any file/line info.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, you know what, that may be it. I was on an Ubuntu 12.04 and had to update gcc and g++ to a newer version for C++11 features for a different project. Since gcc on Ubuntu 12.04 was otherwise stuck at 4.6, it is very likely that the gdb I was using is a couple years older than the gcc.

Comment: Please close this question as duplicate.